# How can I create an Android object recognition application where I can display information when they are clicked using Vuforia and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, model, vuforia, object-recognition

Right now I am trying to create an android object recognition application (it will be through an image) with Vuforia and Unity.
What I will show will be a 3D map, but in addition to showing it I want to present information of certain parts of the model (buildings, etc.) either by pressing it or pointing it at a similar point than in virtual reality..
What I want to create is something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y70yStPCBHA

I am very novice and as much as I try to understand how to do it, I do not succeed. Try searching for information on different websites, but I couldn't find anything similar to the video.

I hope you can help me, I would appreciate it.

I am sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not as complex as you might think. You should try searching for stuff not as a complete structure of every functionality that you need but you should break it down to smaller components.

In the instance you could just serch for how to detect touch on a game object in unity and you can find a lot of stuff about that. It's a good thing to get used to because you can find separate guides for all the components you need and then just combine everything together.

Check this video out about raycasting from touch to game object, it should be everything you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sFrDJKwsdM

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I have to investigate more about Raycasting.